# Please, help me to find out the answer. I don't know much about this ruling.what should I do?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, sunnah

Assalamu alaikum. I'm asking help/ answer .... Im in big problem and i want to know what should/could i have to do !!!
I get married to a converted Muslim girl 15 years ago in Saudi Arabia. Now im living in my own country in Bangladesh with my wife and two kids from seven years, and our financial situation is not good enough. Several times we have argument and fighting each other. Last month she had a chance to go her own country ( Philippines). And she went there 27th july 2020. We don't have argument this time. She just tel that she need to take care of her parents specially her mother. Her parents are non-Muslim ( Christian).. she told me she will come back. Now my two kids and me asking her to come back next month October 1st week.. but she denied to come.. telling this is not so easy . I will come back but don't know when..
Now what is the ruling in islam ..how long she can stay and serve with her Christian parents ? And
Is it permissible in Islam Muslim wife can go back to her non-Muslim parents and privious non-Muslim sons to serve them...???
Please some one answer my question... I'm in depression...

Answer (score 0):

Your post has several questions. I will answer the one that I can.

Q) Is it permissible for your Muslim wife to remain with her Christian parents to take care of them?

A) Absolutely. They are her parents. Regardless of what they believe in. If they need her help, she must oblige and provide assistance to them.

{وَوَصَّيْنَا الْإِنسَانَ بِوَالِدَيْهِ حَمَلَتْهُ أُمُّهُ وَهْنًا عَلَىٰ وَهْنٍ وَفِصَالُهُ فِي عَامَيْنِ أَنِ اشْكُرْ لِي وَلِوَالِدَيْكَ إِلَيَّ الْمَصِيرُ(14) وَإِن جَاهَدَاكَ عَلَىٰ أَن تُشْرِكَ بِي مَا لَيْسَ لَكَ بِهِ عِلْمٌ فَلَا تُطِعْهُمَا ۖ وَصَاحِبْهُمَا فِي الدُّنْيَا مَعْرُوفًا ۖ وَاتَّبِعْ سَبِيلَ مَنْ أَنَابَ إِلَيَّ ۚ ثُمَّ إِلَيَّ مَرْجِعُكُمْ فَأُنَبِّئُكُم بِمَا كُنتُمْ تَعْمَلُونَ} لقمان 15

"But if they (your parents) strive to make thee join in worship with Me things of which thou hast no knowledge, obey them not; yet bear them company in this life with justice (and consideration), and follow the way of those who turn to me (in love): in the end the return of you all is to Me, and I will tell you the truth (and meaning) of all that ye did."

What it means is that your parents must be obeyed in everything, except if they tell you to worship other things.